# LinkButton open new window tab

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnMoreTagRules" runat="server" 
   CommandName='<%#Eval("Value")%>'
   CommandArgument='<%# string.Format("{0}||||{1}", Eval("Tag"), 
       Eval("TagAppearance"))%>' 
   OnCommand="lnkbtnMoreTagRules_Command">Več pravil</asp:LinkButton>
```

I want to close current window tab and open new one.

How can i open a new window tab with linkbutton. `target="_blank"` not helping.

Comment: Which browser you are testing this

Comment: Opening a new tab + closing the current one is nearly identical to opening the page in the same tab - the difference however is that the user won't be able to use the back button in your scenario. Is that your intention?

Answer (score 6):

As link button is posted back, so it cannot be used for a *GET* request. instead use [HyperLink Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

`LinkButton` works like a `Button` and does not have a `Target` attribute. Use a `HyperLink` instead and set the `Target`.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" runat="server" onClientClick="window.open('http://asp.net');"
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt we have any foolprrof code to open link in tabs because most of the browser activities are totally under the control of users.
User can change thier browser settings in the way they wanted to behave.

There is nice discussion related to this in below thread, it will be interesting for you,

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-19843.html