# Open webpage in new tab on imagebutton click

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anybody say how to open web page in new tab on link button click? I have tried the below code but in this case when click any link or image button it will open in new tab, but what I need is to open for particular links only... Can anybody help?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_photo" 
                runat="server" 
                Text="Upload Photo" 
                OnClick="Upload_Photo" 
                OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target='_blank';">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: can you provide your code snippet?

Comment: if you want to change target of your form to _blank, you can do it with c# i.e. OnClientClick="window.document.forms[0].target='_blank';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1154673.aspx?linkbutton+open+in+a+new+window

Your question is also a duplicate of:

1. [link button property to open in new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637087/link-button-property-to-open-in-new-tab)
2. [How to use a Linkbutton to open into a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573714/how-to-use-a-linkbutton-to-open-into-a-new-tab)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" target="_blank">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton
```